# Enabling IPv6 subnet on oracle

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have successfully assigned an IPv6 block to my VCN. When I try to assign a block to my subnet within the same VCN, it asks me to choose an IPV6 CIDR block.

The IPv6 assigned to my VCN: 2603:c020:4002:6c00::/56

I am trying to assign the following to my subnet:

2603:c020:4002:6c91::/64

The GUI lets me edit only the '91' part in there, as demonstrated above.

When I confirm the change, it fails with an error (image attached). I have tried destroying the resources and recreating the VCN, subnet, etc., for troubleshooting. IPv4 works fine, and I can create resources without any hiccups.

Is that a bug in OCI? I have been assigned 2603:c020:4002:6c00::/56 to my VCN. I cannot use 2603:c020:4002:6c91::/64 in my subnet because it belongs to 2603:c020:4002:6c91::/56. I can use 2603:c020:4002:6c00:91::/64 in my subnet. But then, Oracle is not letting me do this and giving me the error "NotAuthorizedOrNotFound". The error is inevitable as 2603:c020:4002:6c91::/64 does not belong to my VCN.

I may be wrong here; my IPv6 skills are not top-notch.

In any case, please help. I am a free tier subscriber and cannot raise a ticket directly.

[image: error-code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a wizard to create the VCN. The wizard is not IPv6 aware, and I assigned an IPv6 manually to it later via the web GUI. The same wizard creates two subnets - one public and one private. I was trying to attach an IPv6 range to those subnets. But it was giving me an error. I created a new subnet in the VCN and was able to assign IPv6 to that subnet.

The solution was - manually create a new subnet in the VCN and add IPv6 to it.